# Can anybody explain the meaning of glob.glob() function in python?

Tags: python, glob

I try to understand it by reading the documentation, but I still don't understand the difference between `recursive=True|False` and why do I need to write '`*`' or '`**`' in path name.

Comment: glob — Unix style pathname pattern expansion. I would say you first need to understand unix style pathname to understand glob.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a wildcard for file names, you can go `\path\*` to retrieve all items in `path` or `\path\*.txt` to retrieve all text files. You can also use `?` for a single character wildcard.

If `recursive` is set to true, `**` acts as a recursion indicator, if you use `\path\**\test?.*` it will look for any file that starts with `test` and has a single character after (e.g. test1, test2) with any extension, inside any subfolder of `path` recursively (thanks to `**`).

Answer (score 1):

`**` has recursive-directory-matching behavior when `recursive=True`.

`recursive=True` is needed to switch **ON** the pattern. Otherwise, `**` is just two separate `*`, each matching zero or more characters.

Until recently the `glob` module did not support recursive matching and there's a lot of code out there that may have  used `**` in patterns thus the Python core developers didn't want to break such code.

Answer (score 1):

if the path name contains only `*`, recursive is not useful; if recursive is False, `**` is no different from `*`. 
only if the path name contains `**` and recursive is True, `**` will match any files.